# How to put the cross on Outlook back where it was?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have recently updated my Outlook 2010 to outlook 2016.  I used to have an easy way to just click on X beside each message, but now the cross is way at the other end of the screen, which requires me to hover my mouse from message to cross, back to next message then cross.

It's small matter, but my daughter recently went onto Outlook 2016 and her X is at the same old place mine used to be.  So I like to know if anyone knows how to set it back?

[image: A before & after image]

Comment: I have Outlook 2016 too, and I'm going to guess you installed a custom addon...

Comment: Microsoft frequently makes changes, it's often annoying when you first see them, but you'll soon get used to the new layout. It's far better in my experience to move forwards then try and live in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've accidentally enabled the "Touch Mode" in Outlook. You just need to [switch back to "Mouse Mode"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-touch-mode-on-or-off-90e162b1-44f9-434f-bc2b-9321c989ea6e).